# Indexing through a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, enumerate

I have a list that I'm trying to loop through and index the number of each number in the list. The total list is around 1500-2000 numbers where each number represents subject behavior. I imported the list of numbers via an excel sheet:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('/data.xlsx')
ws = wb['bhv.TrialError'] 
trialerror10_22=[]
for column in ws.columns:
    for cell in column:
        trialerror10_22=(cell.value)
        print(trialerror10_22)
```

This all works fine and well and prints out my 1500 or so numbers in a list. Next I try to index the numbers, which range from 0 to 9 and are associated with the labels in this order:

```
labels = ['C','NR', 'LR', 'BF', 'NF', 'ER', 'IR', 'LB', 'I', 'A']

def bhvread(trialerror10_22):
    test=False
    results = [0] * (max(data) + 1)
    for val in data:
        results[val] +=1
    return results


for index, val in enumerate(results):
    print(index, labels[index], val)
```

But when I run this part it says `Index Error: list index out of range` and points to the last line of my code.

Output:

```
0 C 1
1 NR 0
2 LR 0
3 BF 0
4 NF 0
5 ER 0
6 IR 0
7 LB 0
8 I 0
9 A 0
```

Comment: I can't really see connection between your code samples. What's the `data` given to `bhvread`? Do you even call the function anywhere?

Comment: why `max(data)+1` ? shouldn't it be `len(data)` ? you're enumerating `results` but you index `labels` so be careful both have the same number of elements at least

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "indexing through" a list and "Next I try to index the numbers, which range from 0 to 9 and are associated with the labels in this order." It would help if you gave a sample of your input and your expected output, because your description is very confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion everyone, I'm obviously not well versed in python but I have a column of numbers in excel that i brought into python using the first part of the data and its in a list called `trialerror10_22` , which, when i print it comes out like this: 
`0
0
0
3
0
0 `           and on and on for 1500 numbers. I want to count how many 0's - 9's there are in my list of numbers. my output looks like this, but doesn't work because of the indexing error.
`0 C 1    
1 NR 0
2 LR 0
3 BF 0
4 NF 0
5 ER 0
6 IR 0
7 LB 0
8 I 0
9 A 0`

Comment: and the formatting of the way the output is looking is wrong, it comes out like a column for the list and the output from the second part.. sorry I'm probably making this really confusing

Comment: i've amended the original post to show what the output is supposed to look like

Comment: what should be printed if after `A` aka the tenth line?

Comment: So the labels aren't to describe the trial number, but the number that encodes for the behavior of the subject.. For example, 0 is equal to a correct response, in my list of however many numbers (which are encoding subject response throughout their session of 1500 trials), i want to know how many correct responses there were. I want to count how many of each number are in my list

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Awesome!!! thank you so much @Altoyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2:**

If I understand you correctly you want to do something like:

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 9, 8]
#dictionary keeping track of our number counters
results = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
labels = ['C', 'NR', 'LR', 'BF', 'NF', 'ER', 'IR', 'LB', 'I', 'A']

for x in data:
    #is the data valid?
    if x >= 0 and x < 10:
        results[x] += 1 #increment the correct entry in the dict

#print everything
for i in range(10):
    print(i, labels[i], results[i])
```

**output**

```
0 C 3
1 NR 2
2 LR 1
3 BF 0
4 NF 0
5 ER 0
6 IR 0
7 LB 0
8 I 1
9 A 1
```

**Original:**

The problem is definitely with `labels[index]`.

If `len(results)` is greater than 10 you will run into troubles on the tenth iteration.

**Example:**

```
results = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
#len(results) = 11

#first run
index    v
results [1   , 2  , 3  , 4   , 5   , 6   , 7   , 8   , 9  , 10   , 11]
labels  ['C','NR', 'LR', 'BF', 'NF', 'ER', 'IR', 'LB', 'I', 'A']

#second run
index          v
results [1   , 2  , 3  , 4   , 5   , 6   , 7   , 8   , 9  , 10   , 11]
labels  ['C','NR', 'LR', 'BF', 'NF', 'ER', 'IR', 'LB', 'I', 'A']

#More runs

#tenth run
index                                                       v
results [ 1  , 2  , 3  , 4   , 5   , 6   , 7   , 8   , 9  , 10   , 11]
labels  ['C','NR', 'LR', 'BF', 'NF', 'ER', 'IR', 'LB', 'I', 'A']

#eleventh run
index                                                              v
results [ 1  , 2  , 3  , 4   , 5   , 6   , 7   , 8   , 9  , 10   , 11]
labels  ['C','NR', 'LR', 'BF', 'NF', 'ER', 'IR', 'LB', 'I', 'A'] #INDEX ERROR!!!
```

It is pretty unclear what you try to accomplish but I hope this gets you on the right track.

**Update:**

As @Elzell said you may want to use `itertools.cycle`

```
import itertools
#...
labels_iterator = itertools.cycle(labels)

for index, val in enumerate(results):
    print(index, labels_iterator.next() , val)
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve with your labels you might use itertools.cycle() to cycle over that list. In the eleventh run you would then have 'C' as 11th label.